# Microservices - getting initial state

Tags: microservices

I am designing a system that stores some certain data and performs some real-time calculations. It's oil industry and there are a lot of integrations with external systems. 
We've chosen the microservices architectural style.

I just wanted to clarify one case...I'll talk abstract.

Imagine that there is a microservice (A) that does some calculations in real-time.
For the calculations it requires some data (parameters, configuration etc.) that is available before it starts. Some data can be changed on fly.

A part of the required data is owned by another microservice (B) and it's available through the pragmatic REST API.
The second part is owned by another microservice (C). So in order for the microservice (A) to function it has to collect the data from 2 different microservices.

I took a desition to store all the data required for calculations in the microservice (A) own database.
So the microservice (A) has its own database with all the info required. There is a duplication of the data across my services, but I consider this to be fine.

Also, there is an asynchronous event-based communication between these 3 services. So whenever the data is changed in ms (B) or (C), (A) will get a notification and adjust it's behavior accordingly.

Now **question 1**.

Even though there is an event-based communication mechanism, that lets MS (A) know about the changes made fly,
MS (A) anyway needs the initial state - all the data from (B) and (C) by the time it starts.
When MS (A) starts, should it call and fetch all the data from (B) and (C) through their APIs to store it its local db???

If yes, another question.
The API of (B) has not been specifically designed for (A). That means (A) will not get JUST what it needs. It will get more than it needs, just because the API of (A) is designed this way, it returns models, the models contain information needed by (A), but it also contain some other information.

Just for example:
Let's say (A) need all ddresses of all users. Just addresses.
But the API of (B) is this:
get /users

```
UserModel
{
id,
name,
address,
status,
some other data
}
```

Let's say my MS (A) needs just address. If (A) calls (B) for getting a user, than (A) will be coupled to UserModel which contains a lot of unnecessary info. Why (A) should know more than it needs to know?

In OOP I would solve it through the interface that I would define in (A) itself.

```
interface IAddressRepository (belongs to (A))
{
    IList<Address> GetAllAddresses();
}
```

Then in the implemntation

```
class AddressRepository : IAddressRepository  (adopter, belongs neither to (A) not to (B), but knows about (A) and (B))
{
    IList<Address> GetAllAddresses()
    {
          //get all users from (B)
          //foreach user retrieve the address
          //compse a list of addresses and return
    }
}
```

So in this case (A) knows just exactly what it needs to know and not more than that.

**Question 2.** How to manage the same for microservices? Is 3rd microservice should act as an adopter?

I appreciate your help!

Please answer these two questions. Straight and structured!

Kind regards,
Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve problem 1 you have a couple of options:

1. If B & C store their events locally, you can do what I've found referred to as "event replay" and load all previous events stored in B & C and replay them in A once you deploy it. This will in-effect bring it up to date, so ti can simply then observe new events.
2. If the above is not possible, you could certainly from A call a web api in B and C to retrieve the data. You can only do this if you use some soft form of deserialization (like json instead of protobuf) but if you can, it's a really good option and guarantees low(-er) couping than relying and having to interpret the entire contract.

   - **EDIT**: In this option while the contract is owned by B, A may not deserialize the entire response payload. Specifically, B may expose a payload with 10 properties, but inside of A you may deserialize it into a structure which only contains the 2 properties which you're interested in without an error being raised (hence soft deserialization). Other (de)serialization methods like protobuf don't allow this, which is why this is case-specific, but with json you're able to not depend on the entire contract, so you don't have such a high coupling between your services
   - **EDIT 2**: As an aside from your question, if you, or another internal team owns service B, you may want to look into domain relationships and try to be explicit in the relationship of the two services and how requirements flow. Some more info about this on: https://culttt.com/2014/11/26/strategies-integrating-bounded-contexts/
3. Another option (quite similar to one above) is to "lazy load" the changes; Once you receive a new event in A notifying you of a change from B, A can then hit via (web request as in previous option) B and/or C to retrieve the version of the entity. This will make your deployments much faster.
4. Another option, if you have ownership or can requerst work in B and C, is to include a golden copy of the resources when the messages are published from B and C, so that A won't need to reach out to retrieve data once they receive the events.

I don't think using microservices changes anything, with the difference being that if it's a monolithic service, you could communicate in-proc (but that wouldn't change the pattern, only some implementation details)

Comment: Please see my post above.

Comment: Hi Savvas, I will go for your 2nd option. Not to overcomplicate things in this dynamically changing world. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for your structured answers. I appreciate! Could you please clarify? 
In option 2 you're talking about the soft deserialization. I kind of guess what you want to say but I have not fully caught it. My (B) exposes REST-like API. The resources exposed and payloads are presented in the form of JSON. Do you agree that the models don't necessary fit the needs of (A)? (A) can fetch whatever it needs for (B) but the way it gathers the required data from the exposed resources is dictated by the API of (B). So the interface is dictated by (B).(A) adopts to it, looking for the required information. So (A) has to call for getting a resource. Than deserialize it and collect all the information required from the deserialized object. It will work of cause, but if we look at the communication interface between (A) and (B) we will notice that (A) consumes more information from (B) that it needs. This fact bothers me a lot as a software architect.
In the lower layers (within a single component), I would easily solve by introducing an interface within (A) that defines what (A) needs from external (Dependency inversion).  And the implementation of this interface out of (A) boundaries, that has references to (A) and (B) at the same time. Sort of dirty adopter. I can do the same on the microservices level, but then my adopter is another microservice.

Option 3 and 4.
Here I understnad what you are talking about. I call it "thin" and "fat" events. Thin is just metadata. You get thin notification, then you fetch resources. Fat - you get a notification with the resources at once, so no need to fetch anything.

Comment: Hello Alexander, as a fyi, it's generally customary in SO to edit the question with added info instead of adding an answer to ask for clarifications. I'll ammend my answer shortly

Comment: I'm personally hesitant to use the terms thin events to describe id-only events. Another interpretation is to have context-specific events, so a command which changed multiple apsects of an entity would raise multiple small events, all containing all properties relevant to that change.

I have seen thin and fat being used as you define it, but it's not universal afaik

Comment: Hi Savvas, sorry I am not a frequent SO user. I thought it was better to add an answer so that some other users could follow the thread ;)

Comment: No worries, just a heads up.